# MOSFET Driven 5V relay doesn't work when connected to two different sources

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, relay, 5v

I built a circuit that uses a 3.3V signal to control an IRLB8721 MOSFET, which in turn switches a common 5V relay. This relay then controls an external 5V powered device. I drew a schematic below. With this circuit, when I use an Arduino power supply with both 3.3V and 5V output to test it, it works as I expect it to. However, as soon as I use a different 5V power supply, the relay does not engage. I made sure to common ground everything, so I don't understand why independent power supplies would not work. Any tips on troubleshooting would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Schematic:
[image]

Comment: The schematics look fine. Perhaps there is an error in the built circuit that can't be determined from the schematics, but a photo from what is actually built?

Comment: There is a Circuit Lab schematic tool in the question editor. You should use it Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly fine. You need a diode across the relay coil to protect the MOSFET from back-emf.  Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: Welcome! Your design is good as you have it drawn. The IRLB8721  MOSFET you have chosen is avalanche rated so you are correct no diode is needed for the relay. What are you driving the gate with? If you have a 100K resistor try replacing your 10K, If that solves the problem your input resistance is to high. If it is a microprocessor the pull down should be on the port pin so it does not divide the gate drive voltage.